# Adding a Vue component to a blade template

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to use a Vue package, VueHighlightJS to display a code block display on a blade template view. This is my first time working with Vue, I've had a look at similar issues - but still cannot get the code to work.

js/app.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'

import VueHighlightJS from 'vue-highlight.js';

import 'vue-highlight.js/lib/allLanguages'
import 'highlight.js/styles/tomorrow-night.css';
Vue.use(VueHighlightJS);

Vue.component('block', require('./components/CodeBlock.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        'block': require('./components/CodeBlock.vue'),
    }
    //router: new VueRouter(routes)
})
```

CodeBlock.vue

```
<template>
    <div>

        <div>
            <div class="block shadow flex items-center justify-center">
                <highlight-code class="min-w-full" lang="javascript">
                    hgghfgg
                </highlight-code>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {

    }
</script>
```

Trying to display view in show.blade.php

```
<head>

    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
    <h1>{{ $snippet->title }} </h1>

    <div>{{ $snippet->description }} </div>

    <div>{{ $snippet->code }} </div>

        <block></block>


    @yield('content')
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you loading the app.js created by your vue application? Please also add the error you are receiving onscreen or in the console.

Comment: Yep. app.js is being loaded in my app.blade.php file. I've also tried adding this into my show.blade.php without any luck
```
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have you shown all the code for you `show.blade.php`? Also, is this the file you're loading from you route/view or is it this the blade file you're extending?